# Bulk Update using Jongo

Tags: mongodb

We can do the bulk update in mongo shell as follows

```
bulk.find( { status: "A" } ).update( { $set: { status: "X", points: "1" } } );
```

via Mongo API

```
 BulkWriteOperation bulkOperation = 
             collection.initializeOrderedBulkOperation();
 BasicDBObject basicObjectToUpdate =....;
           bulkOperation.find(...).upsert().replaceOne(basicObjectToUpdate);
 bulkOperation.execute();
```

Assume i have 1000 records and the collection has 10 columns and i need to update 7 columns.

Do we have a bulk Jongo API to update the collection using single API by passing the set of fields, values?

Thanks.

Comment: Related https://github.com/bguerout/jongo/issues/183

Comment: Is there is any other alternative, chridam or do you suggest any other solution?